# What is the best way to store node(i).x and node(i).y array values in c++?

Tags: c++

I have to process spatial data which are nodes in a graph.What data type /variable type /data structure allows me to access the values of i-th node's x value and i-th node's y value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

std::vector would do it.

ie

```
class Node
{
    std::vector< NODE > mNodes;
public:
    int x, y;
    Node& operator( int i )
    {
        return mNodes[i];
    }
}
```

Now if you have a Node defined as n you can access the ith node stored in that Node as follows:

```
Node n;
// Populate Node
int x = n( 12 ).x;
int y = n( 14 ).y;
```

Comment: a vector of a class within the same class may not compile depending on the implementation or allocator. for example, try replacing it with deque in vs.

Comment: @Inverse: could you explain more deeply ? I have a few reasons in mind but none of them involve the allocator.

Comment: @Inverse:  I've never heard of such a thing.  The vector is a set of references so you don't even need to know they type .  Can you give me an example of this being wrong?  Preferrably a link...

Answer (score 3):

```
struct Node{
    float x;
    float y;
}
std::vector<Node> nodes;
std::cout<<nodes.at(i).x;
```